# max_connections error during restoring PostgreSQL to Local Database

Tags: postgresql, max-connections

I am facing max_connections error during database restoration on ApsaraDB for PostgreSQL in a local database.

I am using below mentioned command for database restoration

```
\i c:/mydb1.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by the large number of connections. To solve this problem, we recommend that you set the max_connections values of both the master and slave instances to 800 or less.

The max_connections values for the master and slave instances are required to be the same. For details, see [Server Configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-connection.html) and [Server Setup and Operation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/kernel-resources.html) on the official website of PostgreSQL.

Please [Click here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/faq-detail/41755.htm) for detailed information.